# How can I disable the system feedback when using the "fn" button on a Touch Bar-equipped MBP?

Tags: keyboard, touch-bar

I use [*Shush*](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shush-microphone-manager/id496437906?mt=12) to auto-mute my microphone on voice and video calls, where I toggle my mic on by holding the <kbd>fn</kbd> key.  But on a Touch Bar equipped MBP, the system issues a *click* and *pop* noise when pressing and releasing the <kbd>fn</kbd> button, and it's driving me batty.

How can I disable this feedback noise?  (And how did you figure this out?)

*Update:* I should note a few settings:

- *System Preferences > Sound > Sound Effects > Play user interface sound effects* is OFF
- *System Preferences > Keyboard > Dictation* is OFF

Comment: If you quit Shush entirely does it still make this noise?

Answer (score 2):

How embarrassing: the clicks were due to Shush's audio cues. I thought I had disabled them.

[image: Shush's preferences]

Comment: Well it's answered now at least we know!

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you have enabled Dictation which is what that key is configured for by default.

You can disable this as follows:

1. Click on the Apple menu
2. Open "System Preferences"

[image]

3. Select "Keyboard"

[image]

4. Select "Dictation"
5. Set "Dictation" to "Off"

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have dictation enabled.

Comment: I see, I was thinking it might be that which is creating the sound. In this same menu there is a shortcuts section, could you check in here carefully to see if any operating system shortcuts are mapped to the fn key?